# First output of delta time always wrong using chrono

Tags: c++, timedelta, c++-chrono

I am trying to make a libary so that I can reuse all my class in future. Down here I have a class that can calculate delta time for fps and other stuffs if needed in future. I noticed that my first output of running always be a negative power up of -7 or more. Is it because I use float to do the calculation that it create this imprecision?

```
class Timer {
public:
    Timer();
    ~Timer();
    void Update();
    float GetDeltaTime() const;

private:
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock> myCurrentTime;
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock> myLastTime;
};

Timer::Timer()
{
    myCurrentTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    myLastTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
}

void Timer::Update()
{
    myLastTime = myCurrentTime;
    myCurrentTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
}

float Timer::GetDeltaTime() const
{
    std::chrono::duration<float> deltaTime = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<float> >(myCurrentTime - myLastTime);
    return deltaTime.count();
}

int main()
{
    Timer myTimer;
    while (true) {
        myTimer.Update();
        std::cout << "Delta time: " << myTimer.GetDeltaTime() << std::endl; //Delta time: 2e-07 more or less it always become like this for first output
        Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rodn5.png)

I tried to cast duration of time to float before the function run but it still produce same result

Comment: To start with, `myCurrentTime = myLastTime = ....` , i.e. chained assignment from single clock read, should probably be on the menu for your construction. And I have no idea what the naked `myCurrentTime;` is intended to do in your `Update` method, but unless you intended it to do nothing, it's falling woefully short of expectations. That said, **don't post pictures of code; *ever***. Post code as properly formatted text.

Comment: Don't use `high_resolution_clock` - see the notes here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock

Comment: Note that you should use `std::chrono::steady_clock` for duration measurements. Please show a [mre] but at a guess you're first call is simply a very short time so produces a very small number

Comment: @AlanBirtles I just edit the post now please check it.

Comment: Yep, your first update is immediately after construction so the time is tiny. Not sure what you expect the result to be?

Comment: @JesperJuhl I tend to use this for something like my own benchmarking so I need it to point out the shortest tick period possible on the current system. But maybe I will have a second look into steady clock.

Comment: @AlanBirtles I hope it can be like 0.00008 but I guess it super super tiny. Sorry this is the first time I use chrono so I tried to play around with it and see what will be best to calculate delta time for fps.